# UITableView stops scrolling when adding new rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView with Cells that have UIImages as main content. The Table View is paginated, so when I'm near the end of the UITableView I make a new Request to the API and insert the new cells (infinit scrolling).

The problem is that when the data from the API arrives, and I add them to the table view, the scrolling stops completly.

I've tried with

```
[tableview reloadData]
```

and

```
[tableview beginUpdates]
[tableview insertRows...]
[tableview endUpdates]
```

But the Scrolling animation stops completly in both cases.

Comment: can you post bit more code ?

Comment: did you checked the cellforrowatindexpath after making the new request?

Comment: @Codecracker thanks to your comment I rechecked my code and found the problem! Silly mistake from me, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I just found the problem: After the new data arrived I had a UIRefreshControl calling `[self.refreshControl endRefreshing]`. And for some reason that method stopped all scrolling animation in the table view.

By adding

```
if ([self.refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

the problem was solved.

Comment: WOW, saved me so much time. Glad you figured this out, and thanks for remembering to update your answer here.

Comment: You just saved me a plethora of time & frustration <3

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5:

```
if self.refreshControl.isRefreshing {
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```